# (Unity) Rapidly click to speed up an object (otherwise decelerate)

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, mouse

I’m trying to have a button that when you click it, cause the speed to increase incrementally for each time you click. When you stop clicking, it begins to slow down. I’ve tried various methods from rigidbody.velocity (didn’t work because object was kinematic), to transform.Translate, to transform.MovePosition. Any help would be appreciated, as I need to figure this out fast.

EDIT: The button being clicked is a sprite.

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    clicked = true;

}
void ifClicked(){
    if (clicked) {
        speed += 0.5f;
        gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        StartCoroutine("Decelerate");
    }
}

IEnumerator Decelerate() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    speed -= 0.5f;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code for it that you have now?

Comment: Unfortunately, my laptop’s battery just went out. I posted this from my phone.

Comment: Alright, what does it do now then?

Comment: Nothing, unfortunately. I don’t have a good enough grasp on methods that make objects move. What worked best was using transform.Translate, but it made for very choppy movement, which wasn’t what I was going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a float which will increase every time you click that button(like a multiplier) and the `transform.position` of that particular gameobject could be translated with that multiplier.

```
// A button could call this function from OnClick()
public void Multiply()
{
    // where multiplier is a member variable of the class you're using this in
    multiplier *= 1.1f;
}

// And add these into Update()
transform.position += movementVector * multiplier * Time.deltaTime;
multiplier *=0.95f;
```

Comment: It's probably really flawed since its 7 in the morning and I haven't fully woken up yet

Comment: Unity doesn't seem to like that. It's giving me an error message that says "Operator '*=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'. Note, I did add the line "Vector3 movementVector;" to my list of variables.

Comment: it seems like it's doing the math, but the object isn't moving anywhere when I click on the button sprite. Is it because movementVector isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: movementVector is the vector you want to move the gameobject by, gotta define it somewhere or it'll be null

Comment: Looks like it's working! It's still a little choppy, though. Would adding a Lerp of some kind help?

Comment: `transform.position += movementVector * multiplier;` has been changed in the new edit to make up for choppiness.
Which would mean that now movementVector would have to be how much you would want to translate the given gameobject per second

Comment: Also, once multiplier has gone below a certain threshold, say 0.01f, you might want to just make it 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180844/discussion-between-ryolu-and-kat-k).